# Finding gradient with use of First Principles

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

To find the gradient of the curve $y = x^n$ at the point $P(a,a^n)$, a chord joining Point P to Point $Q(a+h, (a+h)^n)$ on the same curve is drawn. By finding the gradient of the chord PQ, find the gradient of the tangent to the curve at $x=a$ as a limit when $h \rightarrow 0$

When I first looked at the question, my first thought was that the gradient of tangent = gradient of chord.

However, I fail to find the gradient of chord using First Principle. What is the working to do so?

Comment: I also understand that the gradient of the chord should be $\frac{(a+h)^n-a^n}{h}$ but how do you proceed from that? Since the actual gradient of the curve should be $nx^{n-1}$

Comment: Gradient of the tangent will be the limit of the expression you just wrote as h -> 0

Comment: Yes @Saksham but wouldn't that be just $\frac{0}{0}$?

Comment: If not can you show me how it's done?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be 0/0. I think you'll have to use the binomial theorem to expand (a+h)^n

Comment: Check this out https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+h-%3E+0+%5B%7B(a%2Bh)%5En+-+a%5En%7D%2Fh%5D

Comment: If $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ then you can use binomial expansion to get $y'= nx^{n-1}$.